# consolidating overlapping log files

Tags: regex, shell, unix, logging

I have an application which removes the logs very hastily. It keeps something around 10,000 lines in the log and it is not configurable, thanks to an in-house programmer at one time. New incoming entries, push the bottommost entries out of the log.

So, I have a cron job which takes a snapshot of the log file every hour. On the fast transaction hours, the log overlaps with the previous one by less than a thousand lines but on the slow hours, there is 5-7 thousand lines of overlap.

My purpose is to reconstruct the log as one big log, where only one instance of each line exists. My current train of though to attain such a result is, to go through each line in the latest log file and compare it to all the lines in the previous file and if it doesn't exist, append it to the single log file. But for 5-7K lines, this is a gruesomely long process.is there a tool or way to discover the overlapping sections of a file, such as :

```
log1    log2    log3          Resulting File

1111 ........................ 1111
x1x1 ........................ x1x1
2222 ........................ 2222
3333 ........................ 3333
4444 ........................ 4444
5555 ........................ 5555
6666    6666 ................ 6666
7777    7777 ................ 7777
8888    8888 ................ 8888
        9999 ................ 9999
        aaaa ................ aaaa
        bbbb ................ bbbb
        cccc    cccc ........ cccc
        y1y1    y1y1 ........ y1y1
        dddd    dddd ........ dddd
                eeee ........ eeee
                z1z1 ........ z1z1
                ffff ........ ffff
                gggg ........ gggg
```

Edit : I have updated the result I want to accomplish with a better formatted input and resulting output file representations above.

To make things harder, this log file has no timestamps. Go figure...Although it is not cruicial, it would be nice to know what happened when, but again the purpose of the log is not timing. It is just catching errors and their frequency.

So, this is a regex question I am sure but they are not my strong suit and I have no idea how to capture patterns spanning multiple lines and when I say multiple, it is hundreds or thopusands of lines.

Comment: Do you want to avoid sorting the input files?

Comment: sorting the input files jumbles the order of events taking place. Even though I am not too keen on seeing what happened when, to the minute, I still want to know what happened at what time relative to another event, to determine causality. Also, my log entries are not one liners. One even, can generate up to 15 or so lines of entries in the log, which only makes sense if you look at the log as a whole instead of one line at a time. So, as I mentionoed to the first answer below, sorting is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {print; seen[$0]=1; next} !($0 in seen)' file1 file2
```

This reads, prints and stores the lines in file1 (the "NR==FNR" condition), then, for file2, it will only print the line if they have not been seen in file1

---

Given your update, this can be made more general:

```
awk '! seen[$0]++' log1 log2 ...
```

This may be pretty memory intensive, depending on the size of your files. It has to store all the unique lines, plus whatever overhead of using an associative array.

Also, if an individual file contains duplicate lines, only the first line will be output.

Comment: when I try to run your one liner, I am getting these errors--> awk: syntax error near line 1; awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @Scott - I tested glenn's solution and it worked very well over here. it might be related to the file names you are passing as a parameter.

Comment: the command I ran was **awk 'NR==FNR {print; seen[$0]=1; next} !($0 in seen)' log1 log2** and I got the error messages I wrote previously. Please see my updated file representations in the original question for the log1 and log2 contents

Comment: hmmm strange.. whenI am on a solaris 9 machine, awk command doesn't work, but works fine on a red hat 5 system. It spits out an extroneous blank line at the file border but I can take it out with a grep if push comes to the shove. For the time being, I am set. Thanks Glenn

Comment: On Solaris, the "default" /usr/bin/awk is considered old and broken. Choose `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk` instead

Comment: @glennjackman: the simplified code is doing what I am trying to avoid. It is listing only "one single" occurence of each line regardless where it finds it. On my example in the original post, lets sayy I have line as "1111" between "9999" and "aaaa", it disappears when I run log1 and log2 thru the simplified version of your solution, whereas the original one keeps them intact, which is what I need. Still, thanks for the original one liner.

Comment: The original solution still has this "bug" for file2.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it using uniq

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq > bigFile.txt
```

Comment: if only it was that easy. I want to keep the chronological order of logs, even though the timing is not my main concern, I still need to know which even took place when relative to another event. Also, the log entries are in blocks not only on one single line.